# Reset initial state in React + ES6

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have a class, `ElementBuilder` below, and when the user saves the `Element` they've built, I want the state to reset to the values below.

I have some functions in this class that I haven't provided but that change the state of `title`, `size`, and `color`.

In ES 5, I would have a `getInitialState` function on my class and could call `this.getInitialState()` in a function.

This element lives in my app for the lifecycle of a logged in user and I want the default values to always be the same regardless of past usage.

How do I achieve this without writing a function that sets an object of default values (or maybe that's the answer)? thanks!

```
class ElementBuilder extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            title: 'Testing,
            size: 100,
            color: '#4d96ce',
        };
    }

    resetBuilder() {
        this.setState({ this.getInitialState() });
    }
}
```

Comment: You can always define a constant outside of the class with the initial values. Then use it to initialize the state and to reset at any given time.

Comment: for state management that's robust please take a look at [redux](http://redux.js.org/) with redux you can do all sort of stuff e.g undo, redo and timetravel effortlesly

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You may use a getter function:

```
class ElementBuilder extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = this.initialState;
  }

  get initialState() {
    return {
      title: 'Testing',
      size: 100,
      color: '#4d96ce',
    };
  }

  resetBuilder() {
    this.setState(this.initialState);
  }
}
```

or just a variable:

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);

  this.initialState = {
    title: 'Testing',
    size: 100,
    color: '#4d96ce',
  };
  this.state = this.initialState;
}
```

Comment: A getter function is still a function ;)

Comment: @FelixKling oh, I've missed the "without writing a function" :) But then second option looks good.

Comment: This is fine. Thanks Mikhail and Felix!

Comment: Just a note, I think in the constructor you should call this.getInitialState rather than this.initialState and in the getInitialState function you should use this.setState rather than this.state.

Comment: Should the code in `resetBuilder` be `this.setState(this.initialState);`?

Comment: how can i call this resetBuilder outside this component. Or if it is functional component than how to call outside function component.

Comment: In the second approach, since `this.state = this.initialState;` is a pass by reference, won't it cause issues where we are mutating an object's property?

Answer (score 4):

Using the proposed class fields, you could do something like this:

```
class ElementBuilder extends Component {
    static initialState = {
        title: 'Testing',
        size: 100,
        color: '#4d96ce'
    }
    
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)

        this.state = ElementBuilder.initialState
    }

    resetBuilder() {
        this.setState(ElementBuilder.initialState)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Since the initial state doesn't seem to depend on anything instance specific, just define the value outside the class:

```
const initialState = {...};

class ElementBuilder extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = initialState;
    }

    resetBuilder() {
        this.setState(initialState);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do we set `initialState` as a `class` and not a variable?

Comment: @FelixKling : what is the reason behind `this.setState(intialState)` instead of  using this syntax `this.setState({intialState})` . could you please explain a bit of it .

Comment: @SakthiSureshAnand: `this.setState({intialState})` is the same as `this.setState({intialState: initalState})`, i.e. the state would end up having a single entry, `initialState`. That's not what we want. Every property of `initialState` should be part of the state. For the same reason we do `this.state = initialState;` and not `this.state = {initialState};`.

Comment: After initializing the state, when I update the state it also updates the const object.

Comment: @Jay: Then create a copy. Depending on the structure a shallow copy may be enough. `this.state = {...initialState};`.

Comment: how to call restBuilder() from outside this component or functional component

Answer (score 0):

Use an High Order Component to clear component state (rerender)

Exemple Element.jsx :

```
// Target ----- //

class Element extends Component {

  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    const {
        initState = {}
    } = props
    this.state = {initState}
  }

  render() {
    return (
        <div className="element-x">
            {...}
        </div>
    )
  }
}

// Target Manager ----- //

class ElementMgr extends Component {

    constructor(props){
        super(props)
        const {
            hash = 0
        } = props
        this.state = {
            hash, // hash is a post.id 
            load: false
        }
    }

    render() {
        const {load} = this.state
        if (load) {
            return (<div className="element-x"/>)
        } else {
            return (<Element {...this.props}/>)
        }
    }

    componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
        const {hash = 0} = nextProps
        if (hash !== this.state.hash) {
            this.setState({load:true})
            setTimeout(() => this.setState({
                hash,
                load:false
            }),0)
        }
    }
}

export default ElementMgr
```