# Reset React timer to initial const value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, timer, scope, constants

I'm trying to get my timer app to reset to the initial value in `const initState` when I hit the reset button, but it just stops the timer, without resetting the values. I've tried a number of different solutions on [Reset initial state in React + ES6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45200535/reset-initial-state-in-react-es6), but I've gotten the same results: the reset button just stops the timer, without actually resetting the values. Here's my code so far:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import moment from 'moment';
import './App.scss';
import TimerHeader from './TimerHeader';
import TimerSettings from './TimerSettings';
import TimerDisplay from './TimerDisplay';
import TimerControls from './TimerControls';
import TimerFooter from './TimerFooter';

//set initial state w/default durations, clock set to 'SESSION', and not running

const initState = {
  currentTime: moment.duration(25, 'minutes'),
  sessionTime: moment.duration(25, 'minutes'),
  breakTime: moment.duration(5, 'minutes'),
  label: 'SESSION',
  running: false,
  timer: null 
}

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = initState;

    this.changeSessionTime = this.changeSessionTime.bind(this);
    this.changeBreakTime = this.changeBreakTime.bind(this);
    this.switchLabel = this.switchLabel.bind(this);
    this.switchTimer = this.switchTimer.bind(this);
    this.startTimer = this.startTimer.bind(this);
    this.stopTimer = this.stopTimer.bind(this);
    this.resetTimer = this.resetTimer.bind(this);
    this.countdown = this.countdown.bind(this);
    this.playAudio = this.playAudio.bind(this);
  }

  //new function to set currentTime to either sessionTime or breakTime based on label?

  //change the session and/or break times that are displayed
  changeSessionTime(newSessionTime) {
    this.setState({
      currentTime: !this.state.running && this.state.label === 'SESSION' ? newSessionTime.clone() : this.state.currentTime,
      sessionTime: newSessionTime
    })

  }

  changeBreakTime(newBreakTime) {
    this.setState({
      currentTime: !this.state.running && this.state.label === 'BREAK' ? newBreakTime.clone() : this.state.currentTime,
      breakTime: newBreakTime
    })
  }

  //change the clock setting when an active timer hits 0
  switchLabel() {
    this.setState({
      label: this.state.label === 'SESSION' ? '\xa0' + 'BREAK' : 'SESSION'
    })
  }

  //change the timer from session to break when an active timer hits 0
  switchTimer() {
    this.setState({
      currentTime: this.state.label === 'SESSION' ? this.state.sessionTime.clone() : this.state.breakTime.clone()
    })
  }


  //start the timer when start button is clicked
  startTimer() {
    if (this.state.running) {
      return
    } else {
      this.setState({
        running: true,
        timer: setInterval(this.countdown, 1000)
      })
    }
  }

  //stop the timer when stop (i.e., pause) button is clicked
  stopTimer() {
    if (!this.state.running) {
      return
    } else {
      this.setState({
        running: false,
        timer: clearInterval(this.state.timer)
      })
    }
  }

  //reset the timer when reset button is clicked
  resetTimer() {
    clearInterval(this.state.timer)
    this.setState(initState)
  }

  //reduce timer by the second when running === true
  countdown() {
    if (this.state.running) {
      this.setState({
        currentTime: this.state.currentTime.subtract(1, 'seconds')
      })
    }

    if (this.state.running && this.state.currentTime.get('minutes') <= 0 && this.state.currentTime.get('seconds') <= 0) {
      this.playAudio();
      this.switchLabel();
      this.switchTimer();
    }

  }

  playAudio() {
    const beep = document.getElementById("beep");
    beep.play();
  }


  render() {
    return (
      <div className="container-fluid container-clock">
        <TimerHeader />
        <TimerSettings currentTime={this.state.currentTime} sessionTime={this.state.sessionTime} breakTime={this.state.breakTime} label={this.state.label} running={this.props.running} changeSessionTime={this.changeSessionTime} changeBreakTime={this.changeBreakTime} />
        <TimerDisplay currentTime={this.state.currentTime} />
        <TimerControls startTimer={this.startTimer} stopTimer={this.stopTimer} resetTimer={this.resetTimer} />
        <TimerFooter />
      </div>
    );
  }
}


export default App;
```

Why isn't `resetTimer()` clearing the existing interval, and then putting the initial value to all of the values defined in the beginning 'const initState'? Any insight would be helpful. Thanks!

Comment: Maybe you can see my example below +1

Answer (score 0):

the problem is that you are referencing the same object and then modifying the state, basically instead of doing:

```
this.state = initState;
```

you need to do something like:

```
this.state = Object.assign({}, initState);
```

and that will solve your problem.

Comment: Thank you! I can see why that should work, but unfortunately it's still doing the same thing. Here's what I think is going on: `Object.assign()` clones `initState` and assigns those values to `this.state`. In theory, this should mean that any time state is changed, `initState` still remains the same. Yet the `resetTimer()` function is still not working this way...not sure what I'm missing here.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const initState = {
  number: 0,
  timer: null 
}

class App extends React.Component {
   constructor() {
      super();
      this.state = initState;
      this.start = this.start.bind(this);
      this.stop = this.stop.bind(this);
   }
   start() {
     const { timer } = this.state;
     if (timer) return null;
     this.setState({
       timer: setInterval(() => {
         this.setState({
            number: this.state.number + 1,
         });
       }, 200),
     });
   }
   stop() {
    const { timer } = this.state;
    clearInterval(timer);
    this.setState(initState);
   }
   render() {
     const { number } = this.state;
      return(
        <div>
          <div>{number}</div>
          <button onClick={this.start}>Start</button>
          <button onClick={this.stop}>Stop</button>
        </div>
      );
   }
}
```

This should work, you can see example here: https://jsfiddle.net/iamgutz/t72zv9y8/18/

Comment: @stephan maybe you can try my example if you didn’t see it.

Comment: I saw that, thank you. I'm still not entirely sure why your solution works...you're creating `initState` as a `const`, and setting that value to the state in the constructor...but why does the `stop()` method allow you to reset the timer?