# How to update the state to its previous state in React + Typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, ecmascript-6, setstate

I want to set the state to its previous value. I have a list of checkboxes and based on it selections and click of "Apply" the columns in the table gets shown/hidden. I am able to achieve this functionality. But on click on "Cancel" , I am not able to set it to previous state.

CodeSandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/funny-browser-2z3s5

On click of Cancel, the checkboxes should be set to previous state.

Click is handled with a function in SelectComponent.tsx, the goal is to reset `optionsArr` to its original value:

```
cancelSelection = (event: any) => {
  this.setState({ showList: false });
  this.setState((prevState: any) => ({
    // Isn't working
    optionsArr: prevState.optionsArr
  }));
};
```

Comment: I voted to close because it relies on third-party content (codesandbox) that is subject to change/removal. If this happens, this question will not make sense, thereby eliminating any usefulness to future users. It also means that there are minimal code-related search terms in you question, reducing the ability of search engines to index your question. Please present your code using the tools provided by SO, considering [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and [this](http://sscce.org/) for guidance.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/377959/use-of-codesandbox-vs-built-in-code-snippets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The argument that [setState updater](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate) gets is state at the time the change is being applied. Setting state equal to that changes nothing.

You need to keep track of previous state separately. For example as separate item in the state, an instance variable or the `props`. See for example:

[Reset initial state in React + ES6](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45200535/1630906)

[Clearing state es6 React](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34845650/1630906)